# Sync google chrome bookmarks on two different pc

Tags: google-chrome, sync, bookmarks

I have a laptop and also a pc . and i use google chrome on both for web browsing.so here is my problem . when i use pc and save bookmarks. i have to save those bookmarks manually on a laptop. so i want to know is it possible to sync two google chrome browsers on two different machines with same user of gmail.

Comment: Yes, it is! Go to settings and it is pretty simple. Just log in from settings and configure the sync as you will.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to Menu -> Sign In to Chrome and sign in with your google account on both PC.

You can access your bookmarks, passwords, history, extensions, settings, themes etc. on both machines. Google saves this data in cloud under [chrome sync](https://www.google.com/settings/chrome/sync?hl=en)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

One option is to sign in to Chrome.

Google.com : [Why sign in to Chrome](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/165139?hl=en)